# when using semantic_form_for accurs "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `my_leaders_path' for #<#<Class...)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, renderpartial

**model**:

```
class MyLeader < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize
  belongs_to :interviewer
  attr_accessible :interviewer_id, :is_leader, :content
  enumerize :is_leader, :in => %w[yes no]
end
```

**controller:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyLeader,  :namespace => :fieldwork do
 form do |f|
   render :partial => 'content'
 end
end
```

**rake routes:**

```
  batch_action_fieldwork_my_leaders POST    /fieldwork/my_leaders/batch_action(.:format)                        fieldwork/my_leaders#batch_action
                        fieldwork_my_leaders POST   /fieldwork/my_leaders(.:format)                                     fieldwork/my_leaders#create
                     new_fieldwork_my_leader GET    /fieldwork/my_leaders/new(.:format)                                 fieldwork/my_leaders#new
                    edit_fieldwork_my_leader GET    /fieldwork/my_leaders/:id/edit(.:format)                            fieldwork/my_leaders#edit
                         fieldwork_my_leader GET    /fieldwork/my_leaders/:id(.:format)                                 fieldwork/my_leaders#show
                                             PUT    /fieldwork/my_leaders/:id(.:format)                                 fieldwork/my_leaders#update
                                             DELETE /fieldwork/my_leaders/:id(.:format)                                 fieldwork/my_leaders#destroy
```

**_content.html.erb:**

```
<div style="width:80%;margin-left:400px">
    <%= semantic_form_for MyLeader.new do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :interviewer_id, :as => :hidden%>
        <%= f.input :is_leader%>
        <%= f.actions do %>
        <%= f.action :reset, :as => :button %>
        <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**The ERROR is:**

```
   ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `my_leaders_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fadc5f8cdf0>:0x007fadc3d929e8>):
```

Why this happened: undefined method `my_leaders_path'?
should that be fieldwork_my_leaders_path?

Comment: new_fieldwork_my_leader_path - is the path for rendering form for new record.

Comment: @misha then why this "undefined  method `my_leaders_path'"  occurred? Is this meaning the "MyLeader.new" in "<%= semantic_form_for MyLeader.new do |f| %>" gave the path  "my_leaders_path"?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your form cost you an issue.

Here is example from documentation.

Partials
If you want to split a custom form into a separate partial use:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  form partial: 'form'
end
```

Which looks for something like this:

app/views/admin/posts/_form.html.arb

```
active_admin_form_for resource do |f|
 inputs :title, :body
 actions
end
```

This is a regular Rails partial so any template engine may be used.

Make sure that you put _content.html.erb in right folder.